# Sum All Invoices Against Multiple Row PO Line Detail

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which retrieves all Purchase Order line detail, with item specific information on each line related to cost.  I wanted to validate this PO total cost detail with a cross reference to our Accounts Payable table.  I assumed one PO would have one invoice; that was incorrect.  I wanted to joint the payment(s) next to each row of any given PO.  I would then be able to Sum my PO line detail and then use an average of the payment to calculate a variance between the PO detail and the actual payment from AP.  My query returns all payments to one PO, creating a duplication problem.

Is there a simple way to Sum all payments against one distinct PO?

My current select statement is pretty simple and left joins the AP payment column to the PO received rows.  If I had a one to one relationship between PO numbers and Invoice payments, I wouldn't have this issue.  Alas, here we are.  I'm using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio to drive the query.

[image: Image of Data Output and Desired End Result]

Comment: Please post your current attempt...

Comment: Yes, please show what you've tried that doesn't work.  You'll likely need a subquery using group by and aggregation.

Comment: [Sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/) is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Answer (score 0):

you could use the following

```
SElect  SUM (actualPOAmount), sum(extpoAmount) , PO.PONUM
FRom PO_Table   PO (nolock) 
JOIN PO_Invoice INV  (nolock) on INV.PONUM = po.PONUM
group by PO.PONUM
```

Comment: The use of the term "validate" contradicts your use (and lack of explanation or warning) of NOLOCK. Quite simply, do not use hints unless you understand and accept the risks they carry.